# downloading file from FTP gets stuck when running Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, ftp, ftp-client

I'm trying to download a file from FTP in my test.
When I'm running this from my local PC or on BrowserStack it works perfectly but when I upload it to jenkins it gets stuck in the line.
I can't understand what is the difference why doesn't it run on Jenkins?
I managed to create a connection to the FTP. the code shown below is the method that downloads the file.

> boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile, outputStream);

```
    public static File downloadFileFromFtp(String fileName, String ftpFilePath, String downloadDirectory, String fileExtension, ExtentTest test) throws Exception {
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect(AutomationPropeties.ftpHost, Integer.valueOf(AutomationPropeties.ftpPort));
    ftpClient.login(AutomationPropeties.ftpUsername, AutomationPropeties.ftpPassword);
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    System.out.println("loged in ftp");
    if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Connected Succesfuly to ftp server.");
        System.out.println("loged in ftp");
    } else {
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Failed connecting to ftp.");
        System.out.println("not loged in ftp");
    }
    String remoteFile = ftpFilePath + fileName + ".xlsx";
    System.out.println(remoteFile);
    // File downloadFile = new File(downloadDirectory+fileName+".xlsx");

    File downloadFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".xlsx");
    System.out.println("reached the try");
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile))) {
        System.out.println("finished with the output");
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile, outputStream);
        System.out.println("retrive the file & conection closed");
        if (success) {
            test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "File was downloaded succesfuly");
        } else {
            test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Failed to download file");
        }
    } finally {
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    }
    return downloadFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Jenkins [FTP plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over) is what you need.  Jenkins can be defined with worker bee (so much better than slave, don't you think?) servers so your job may run on different physical servers.

If you look into the plugin please report back if that helped.

**Update**

Use:

```
curl -O ftp://server/path/to/file
```

Comment: this is for uploading file, I need to download a file from ftp in my test.

Answer (score 0):

This is Mukul from BrowserStack. We have recently released a [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BrowserStack+Plugin) that might help you out.